# Bootstrap Typeahead - no results found

Tags: typeahead.js, typeahead

Using TypeAhead 0.10.4, I want to display a non-selectable message when no results are found by a query. How do I do this? I've tried adding typeahead-no-results to my input control but that doesnt seem to work

```
<input  type="text" runat="server" id="addressTypeAhead"  typeahead-no-results="No address found">



$('.typeahead').on('typeahead:selected', function (evt, item) {
        // set hidden var
        $('*[data-name="addressId"]').val(item.identifier);
    })

    // Instantiate the Typeahead UI
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({ minLength: 3 }, {
        displayKey: 'value',
        valueKey: 'identifier',
        items: 5,
        source: addresses.ttAdapter()
    });
```

I'm getting addresses from Bloodhound elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({ minLength: 3 }, {
    ....
    source: addresses.ttAdapter(), templates: {
        empty: '<div class="tt-no-result">No results found.</div>'
    }
});
```